# Django templates count total in forloop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the folowing code in Django templates.

```
{% if levels %}
    {% for l in levels %}
        <tr>
            <td class="level">{{ l.skill }}</td>
            {% for e in employees %}
                {% if e.skill_level_id == l.id %}
                    <td class="race">{{ forloop.counter0 }}</td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

What this gives me is something like the following (in HTML table):

```
level1  1  5
level2  4  2  6  3
```

Which means 2 employees at level1 (1 and 5) and 4 employees in level2.  What I would like is the total of each level:

```
level1  2
level2  4
```

I'm not sure if I should use forloop.counter, forloop.counter0 or forloop.parentloop.counter?  Or something completely different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than looping and filtering, you should use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) to group your objects into skill levels. Something like:

```
{% regroup employees by skill_level as employees_by_level %}
{% for level in employees_by_level %}
    <tr>
        <td class="level">{{ level.grouper.skill }}</td>
        <td class="count">{{ level.list|length }}</td>
        {% for e in level.list %}
            <td class="race">{{ forloop.counter0 }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Note you'll need to have employees sorted by skill_id in the first place for this to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for the regroup option - this helped tremendously!  Just a note: I believe level.list|count should be level.list|length.  The count function raised an error.

Comment: The first line should also be: regroup by skill_level_id.  Also, level.grouper.skill does not produce anything?